# Does Quarkus support Apache Camel Saga?

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

Does Quarkus has extention for Apache Camel Saga? I tried my hands on an example that uses Spring Boot with Camel saga but couldn't make it work with Quarkus.

Thanks
Kunal

Answer (score 0):

The list of supported camel components is here: https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/list-of-camel-quarkus-extensions.html and so far no, we don't support camel-saga but you are very welcome to open an issue on the camel-quarkus project page https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus